# How to figure out if a host authenticates via LDAP

Tags: shell-script, authentication, ldap

I would like to automate a check (in shells script) that verifies whether the account that is currently logged in is a local account or whether it authenticates via LDAP.

Since there are various LDAP clients for different Linux / Unix flavors, I was wondering whether there is a definite method to verify that across all / most Linux / Unix-flavors (e.g. checking whether /etc/ldap/ldap.conf is configured correctly).

Answer (score 1):

To check if the current account is an LDAP account, you can use `w`:

```
[root@hostname.domain.com /]# w
 17:09:30 up 2 days,  4:49,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
DOMAIN.C pts/0    192.168.10.11  17:08    2.00s  0.07s  0.21s sshd: user@domain.com [priv]
root     pts/1    192.168.10.11  17:09   20.00s  0.01s  0.01s -bash
```

Notice that the domain user listed is different than the local root user.

To check if LDAP is configured properly on all systems, setup a test LDAP account and try to login to each server with those credentials.